# AWS CodeDeploy Keeps Failing - Is it my appspec.yml config causing this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I'm attempting to troubleshoot my failed deployments and cannot locate any logs for CodeDeploy.

I have a CentOS 7 server with a website running on Apache at /var/www/html/. `reset.sh` is suppose to reset file/folder permissions after a deployment.

My appspec.yml looks like this:

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /*
    destination: /var/www/html/
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: reset.sh
      timeout: 3000
      runas: centos
```

Comment: Your appspec file looks fine to me. What kind of errors were you seeing for your failed deployment? The log dir is at /var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent.

Answer (score 1):

There were two main configuration issues that prevented this from working -

1. I needed an IAM Instance Profile (not to be confused with the IAM Role created for CodeDeploy).

   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/how-to-create-iam-instance-profile.html
2. Secondly, after I launched my target instance with this profile attached, I had to install the CodeDeploy agent on my server.

Once this was in place I started to see event errors which let me know that my source needed to be `/` rather than `/*`.